# ReactJs - state is rendered properly but inside method, shows wrong value

Tags: reactjs

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log(this.state);

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });

    console.log(this.state);

  }

render() {
    return (
        {this.state.counter}
    );
  }
```

The output is clearly 1 in the screen
But both console.log is outputting 0.

I was doing a quiz app in reactjs. Same problem happened. Answered, correct Answers are always one less than the real values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setState` doesn't immediately mutate the state.

Check the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

To really check the updated state, you can do the following:

```
this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, {
  counter: this.state.counter + 1
}), function () {
    console.log(this.state.counter);
});
```

Also as per the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.
>   Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

the initial changes to state should be done in constructor as `componentWillMount` won't re-render your component. Or you are better off with `componentDidMount`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So i need to do something like this. `let count = this.state.counter + 1; this.setState({ ...this.state, counter: count}); if(count === 10) { //redirect }`

Comment: I would recommend having 2 components: Quiz, Question.
Quiz would keep the counter and would pass the counter state to the Question component. Now, Question would display the required question as per the counter prop received.

Comment: Would make sense if you ask a different question as people would be able to help you out better with code samples and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous , so there is no guarantee that you will see updated state value on the next line. If you want to make sure that the new value reflect in second console.

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log(this.state);

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        counter: this.state.counter + 1
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
  });

}

render() {
    return (
        {this.state.counter}
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is being changed for the first time before the component has been mount. After that the state isn't changed again so the render isn't triggered and therefore your counter isn't updated.

Try with `componentDidMount` instead.